# Delete Power Query queries' custom XML data using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerquery

I have Power Query queries in an Excel 2010 file and would like to delete these queries using VBA. so far I can achieve that manually with the following steps:

1. unload Power Query addin
2. run Document Inspector and click to delete Custom XML data

The Macro recorder record the following code for step 2.

```
Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
'
'
ActiveWorkbook.RemoveDocumentInformation (xlRDIPrinterPath)
ActiveWorkbook.RemoveDocumentInformation (xlRDIDocumentProperties)
ActiveWorkbook.RemoveDocumentInformation (xlRDIInactiveDataConnections)
End Sub
```

However, using this macro I do not achieve the same result (=PQ query code gone from the workbook).

Any ideas on how to achieve the PQ query codes to be removed using VBA?

Answer (score 0):

This code will delete the custom part, but you will have Power Query connections, and possibly TableObjects, and DataModels left in your workbook.  Trying to refresh will give you errors.

```
Sub DeletePowerQueryCustomXml()
  Set parts = ActiveWorkbook.CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace("http://schemas.microsoft.com/DataMashup")
  For Each part In parts
    part.Delete
  Next part
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For Excel 2016 preview, there are new VBA objects which enable us to better handle PQ programmatically. E.g. check out Sub DeleteQuery() at:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/VBA-to-automate-Power-956a52d1

However for those of us stuck on Office 2010, this doesn't yet seem possible.